# symmetric decreasing rearrangement

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\left[0,\infty\right)$ be a continuous function. We denote by $f^{*}$ the symmetric decreasing rearrangement for $f$. Is it possible to guarantee that $f(0)\leq f^{*}(0)$?

Comment: Maybe I'm alone, but I don't know what a symmetric decreasing rearrangement is.

Comment: @Randall When I read the problem, I also thought the same. Let's hope the OP adds an explanation for that.

Comment: No idea, until you define "symmetric decreasing rearrangement".

Comment: Then we should be looking it up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_decreasing_rearrangement).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this follows from the fact that $f^\ast(0)$ is the (essential) supremum of $f$.  Indeed, we have that
$$
f(0) \le \Vert f \Vert_{L^\infty} = f^\ast(0).
$$